# How to find a counter-example for the 4th Axiom of Scalar Products?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I was given the following $\langle  U, V \rangle = 3U_1V_1 + 2U_1V_2 + 2U_2V_1 + U_2V_2$ and I was asked to demonstrate if its  a scalar product or not.

I've tested the first three axioms and they all worked out to be true for the given expression.

Now, I have trouble with the 4th Axiom ($\langle U, U \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle U, U \rangle = 0\iff U = 0$ (positive definite) This is the definition from my lecture slides. )

If I try to find a counter-example, there seems to be two ways to do it.

1) Finding a vector u that gives $\langle u , u \rangle =$ a negative value.

2) Finding a vector $u$ that is negative but gives $\langle u, u\rangle  = 0$.

I am not too sure if their valid and I dont know how to test it (How does the plug and chugg work in that case? i.e: how do I do I compute $U_1U_2$? Do I use the  standard scalar product of $\mathbb{R}^2$?)

I know in advance that its not a scalar product because it doesn't verify the 4th axiom (I know this because I know the answer, I am interested in knowing how come).

**For future problems like these, what if the expression was a scalar product. How would I go about proving it knowing that finding counter-examples didn't work to disprove it?**

Comment: Please use MathJax

Comment: What is MathJax?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "negative vector". What you would need is a vector $u$ that is **nonzero** but whose inner product with itself is $0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: So... you've checked three properties of the inner product, but you don't know how to compute "$U_1U_2$"? Then how exactly did you manage to verify those three properties? he entries of the vectors are real numbers; you multiply them as real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\bigl\langle(u_1,u_2),(u_1,u_2)\bigr\rangle&=3{u_1}^2+4u_1u_2+{u_2}^2\\&=(2u_1+u_2)^2-{u_1}^2.\end{align}So, now it's easy: you take, for instance, $u_1=1$, and $u_2=-\frac12u_1=-\frac12$. Then$$\bigl\langle(u_1,u_2),(u_1,u_2)\bigr\rangle=0^2-1^2=-1<0.$$

Comment: Oh thanks, I see now. Can you also tell me what to do in the case no counter-examples are found? How do I prove that the expression fulfill the 4th axiom?

Comment: @Dr.Stone: How did you prove the first three?

Comment: @Dr.Stone For instance, you express it as a sum of squares.

Comment: By just showing that the first part of the equation can be manipulated to give the equality. i.e. developing < cU, V > until I arrive to c < U, V >.